# How to use SQL query in Visual Studio 2022 to filter data and insert the result into an existing table

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access

I have a project with visual studio 2022 using Microsoft access database. I have a table shown as below:

Student Info

```
Name  Student_Class Individual_Marks
Jane        5A            70
Jade        5B            60
Jean        5A            30
Jade        4B            20
```

I'm able to filter and sum the data into table like below (with the check of preview data) using the code provided from amazing people on stack overflow!:

```
SELECT 
    Student_Class As Class, 
    Sum([Individual_Marks]) As [Total_Marks]
FROM 
    [Student Info]
GROUP BY
    Student_Class
```

```
Class Sum Marks (New Table)

Class Total_Marks
5A        100
5B        60
4B        20
```

However, I need to generate a chart using the new table above.
The problem is, when I generate the chart, it comes out blank. I'm thinking it might because the data is only filter but not insert into the table (table name is Class Sum Marks, it is currently blank, on MS Access Side).
Therefore, with all due of respect, I am wondering how I can make this happen, I've tried using INTO and UPDATE but it just come out as error. I'm sorry I new to this TT

Answer (score 0):

The select query results are not persistent insert the records of your select statement into :

```
insert into [Class Sum Marks] (Class, Total_Marks) 
select
    Student_Class, 
    Sum([Individual_Marks])
from
    [Student Info]
group by 
    Student_Class
```

Comment: First of all thanks for commenting @massimiliano. But how can I insert this into existing table (my existing table is called [Class Sum Marks])? I tried using the code you kindly provided but it mention failed to get schema for this query. Also, the **create table** function in visual studio it mention not supported TT

Comment: @JaneLam, i updated my answer to insert the rows in your existing table, please let me know if this helps or paste any error you get

Comment: Hi @Massimiliano Carosi, I tried using the newer code you provided but I still get the error mention Generated SELECT statement. Failed to get schema for this query.

Comment: Hi @Massimiliano Carosi, I have figure it out! It is a silly mistake, actually in the code that load the data into the chart and the table `Me.Class_Sum_MarksTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.FYPDataSet.Class_Sum_Marks)`, that "FillBy" part should have change to the method name I firstly created ==ll, which is the code I show in my post. Even my access there the table is still blank but now my chart is showing, anyway thank you so much for assisting!!